# I'm working with MiKTeX, TeXstudio and writing letters with KOMA-Script and get the following warning "Unused global option(s): [dieter]."

Tags: koma-script, letters, grouping, options

My `dieter.lco` file includes besides personal information the following lines

```
\ProvidesFile{dieter.lco}[2022/01/08 scrlttr2 options]  
\RequirePackage{ngerman}                
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\RequirePackage{graphicx}               
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=None}
\KOMAoptions{
        paper=a4,
        pagenumber=botcenter,
        fromalign=right,
        fromrule=afteraddress,
        fromphone,
%       fromfax,
        fromlogo,fromurl,fromemail,
        backaddress,
        foldmarks,
%       headsepline,footsepline,
%       enlargefirstpage
}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Dr.\, Dieter Kraft}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Brucker Feldweg~2\\82234 Weßling}`
```

My LaTeX file is processed with pdflatex and starts with the following line

```
\documentclass[dieter]{scrlttr2}
```

There is no other warning or error message between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.
But all the information in `dieter.lco` is missing. When I copy `dieter.lco` into the LaTeX file
the letter looks perfect.

Why does the inclusion of the option dieter for the class scrlttr2 not work?

Comment: If I use the test file `\documentclass[dieter]{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}

\end{document}` in texlive 2021 I get no warning and the dieter.lco file  is input.

Comment: that is `Document Class: scrlttr2 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (letter)` what version do you have reported in the log file?

Comment: where did you store dieter.lco? Is it found if you do \input{dieter.lco} in your file?